# useSelector doesnot update the UI

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have a nested state like :

```
bookingDetails = {
jobCards: [
    {
        details_id: '1',
        parts: [
            {...},
            {...}
        ]
    }
]}
```

Now I got the respective `jobCards` in component from props from parent component i.e `detailsID` by using `useSelector`:

```
    const jobCard = useSelector(state => state.bookingDetails.jobCards.find(item => item.details_id === detailsID))
```

I got a `button` that successfully adds new object in `parts` in respective jobCards but that doesnot update the UI.
My `bookingDetails` Reducer:

```
case 'ADD_PARTS':
        return {
            ...state,
            jobCards: state.jobCards.map(jobCard => {
                if (jobCard.details_id === action.id) {
                    jobCard.parts = [...jobCard.parts, { _id: uuid(), name: '' }]
                }
                return jobCard
            })
        }
```

Comment: console log jobCard in ui component. share it here. Then will see whats the issue.

Comment: the state updates, the component is a `bootstrap modal` so when i close and reopen, the UI renders correctly and console.log works fine inside the modal too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to add return statement.
The reducer should have been:

```
 case 'ADD_PARTS':
        return {
            ...state,
            jobCards: state.jobCards.map(jobCard => {
                if (jobCard.details_id === action.id) {
                    return {
                        ...jobCard,
                        parts: [...jobCard.parts, { id: uuid(), name: ''}]
                    }
                }
                return jobCard
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
const [isJobUpdated, setIsJobUpdated] = useState(false);

const jobCard = useSelector(state => state.bookingDetails.jobCards.find(item => item.details_id === detailsID))

useEffect(() => {
   setIsJobUpdated(!!jobCard.length);

}, [jobCard])

return (
   <>
     {isJobUpdated && <YourComponent />
   </>
)
```

NOTE: this is not the best way to do. You might face re-render issue. Just to check if this solve your current issue.

Comment: I did not get initial render maybe because `isJobUpdated` is set to false

Comment: for experient ```const jobCard = useSelector(state => state.bookingDetails.jobCards.find(item => item.details_id === detailsID))``` split this to ```const jobCard = useSelector(state => state.bookingDetails.jobCards)``` and then do the find later. 

or you could miss to dispatch again once the modal trigger.